# Am I confused about the message of the "Monday Morning" folk song?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, folk

I've listened many times to this:

I recognize that I may be completely wrong, and probably are (judging by how often I've misinterpreted lyrics in the past), but is not the "twist" in the final part of this song that the young woman/girl actually regrets marrying the man, and wishes that it was once again "Monday Morning", when she has not yet realized that she regrets it?

Or is it simply that the girl sings, once again, that she wishes that it was already Monday Morning, because then she will be happily married?

Is this intended to be ambiguous? Am I just an idiot who has to over-interpret or confuse simple lyrics?

Comment: Do you have the name of the artist, name of the album or the lyrics to the song?

Comment: I like the Peter, Paul, and Mary version better https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpuYF0FFlsA

Comment: Lyrics https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/6846744/Peter%2C+Paul+and+Mary/Monday+Morning

Answer (score 1):

My take is she was warned to not marry at her age and she didn't heed the warning. She married and then wished she could go back to before she married.

Answer (score -1):

The lyric in question is

> Next Monday night when I go to my bed
> And I turn round to the man that I've wed
> Around his middle my two arms I will fling,
> And I wish to my soul it was Monday mornin'

As so written, it's fairly unambiguous that she's still looking forward to getting married.

What makes the song feel ominous is the minor key and the dire warning provided earlier by the narrator. But at least in this version of the lyrics, there's no actual twist.